# What can I use as placeholders in es6 array destructuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntactic-sugar

I don't like the `, ,` here:

```
let colors = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
let [ , , thirdColor] = colors;
```

Can I use some placeholders characters? I'd rather not introduce unused variables, I just want to make the code look clearer. Right now the only thing I can think about are comments:

```
let [/*first*/, /*second*/, thirdColor] = colors;
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no concept of a placeholder in JS. Often `_` is used for this, but you can't actually use it more than once in one declaration:

```
let [_, secondColor] = colors; // OK
let [_, _, thirdColor] = colors; // error
```

Also, `_` may actually be used in your code, so you'd have to come up with another name, etc.

The simplest way may be to access the third element directly:

```
let thirdColor = colors[2];
let {2: thirdColor, 10: eleventhColor} = colors;
```

Comment: Should `[_, _, thirdColor]` actually produce an error? Firefox's implementation allows it; I haven't not dived into the spec to see if that's wrong.

Comment: `[_, _, thirdcolor] = ....` and `let [_, _, thirdColor] = ...` are different. The first one is fine, since it's just a variable assignment, but the second is a variable declaration and `let` doesn't allow re-declarations. Firefox also throws an error in that case: `(function() { "use strict"; let [_, _,] = [1,2]; }())` gives `TypeError: redeclaration of let _`.

Comment: Oh, I was testing the top-level scope, which apparently does allow `let` re-declarations. (Indeed, I can appreciate that `let` isn't particularly meaningful when your variable has top-level visibility, so I can see why there might be different behavior there.) When I move it inside a function or a block, it indeed throws an error.